# Integer value of strings

Tags: java

How can I convert "1,000" (input obtained as a string) to an integer?

Comment: Learn basics of Integer in java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    int i = df.parse("1,000").intValue();
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: A generic approach colud be like this. 
    Integer.parseInt("1,000".replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""))

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf("1,000".replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Comment: better : System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1,000".replaceAll("\\D+", "")));

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: It's programming with a positive attitude ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
String stringValue = "1,000";

String cleanedStringValue = stringValue.replace(',','');

int intValue = Integer.parseInt(cleanedStringValue);
```

Comment: Becuase for some reason it was not rendering the code properly when the comments were included! Pardon me but Im new to all of this stackoverflow stuff!

Comment: Look at 3rd revision here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5470551/revisions which is made by me. It shows comment and code both well.

Answer (score 1):

ParseInt:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Does not work. See documentation "The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value."

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at this class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all comma with empty string and then use convert.ToInt32();

```
string str = "1,000";
int num = Integer.parseInt(str.replace(",",""));
```

Comment: I need to perform the conversion in java!

Comment: @user673218 - This is available in java too ;)

Answer (score 0):

with a comma (`,`) in the the string you probably cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str ="1000";
```

Try this

```
 int i = Integer.valueOf("1,000".replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt("1000");
```

Prefer avoiding "magic numbers"

```
String num = "1000";
Integer.parseInt(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like the following.

```
String str = "1000";
int result;
try {
    result = Integer.parseInt(str);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.err.println("That was not an integer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always prefer to use `Long.ValueOf` instead of new Long. Indeed, the new Long always result in a new object whereas `Long.ValueOf` allows to cache the values by the compiler. Thanks to the cache, you code will be faster to execute.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).